# Поиск скрипта и участка кода подгружающего inline-стиль

Tags: firefox

Например, здесь [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как найти скрипт и участок кода, который подгружает inline-стиль с помощью инструментов разработчика в Firefox? 
.tpl файл имеет код вот такой:

```
<ul class="items items-catalog items-h-carousel items-product animateListItems">
                        {getOPI($products, array('opi_widget'=>true, 'opi_wishlist' => true))}
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Отключайте скрипты по одному, пока стиль не исчезнет :)

Comment: всё логично, но это не решает проблемы

Comment: Когда исчезнет, читайте содержимое последнего отключенного скрипта, чтобы найти в нём причину проблемы :)

Comment: Но если делать не столь тупо, я бы, руководствуясь логикой, поискал бы скрипты, в которых упоминается `items-h-carousel`, `animateListItems` или число `1170` (умеет ли Firefox определять, какой скрипт отредактировал стили, я, увы, не в курсе)